# What are the advantages of Cobb-Douglas over a translog function?

Tags: production-function, empirical-methods

I am carrying out an empirical study wherein I have to judge productivity for two inter-country alliances. While the translog is a better method theoretically the coefficients are insignificant, whereas in Cobb-Douglas they are significant. The gamma stat also shows a better fit for Cobb-Douglas. Is there any reason as to why Cobb-Douglas can be preferred over translog?

Comment: Could you explain what a "gamma stat" is? With OLS, it is mathematically not possible to obtain a poorer fit (in terms of $R^2$ or SSR) for a more general function than Cobb-Douglas. How do you measure the fit?

Comment: This might help:

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18998/why-is-the-cobb-douglas-production-function-so-popular