# Balanced growth path in the Hicks neutral technology and CES function

Tags: solow, ces-function, balanced-growth

In an another post (Balanced growth path definition in the Hicks neutral steady state with technology), the problem of having a not stationary steady state in a Solow model with Hicks neutral technological shock was addressed.

It was proven that in the case of $Y_t = A_tF(K_t,L_t)$, the rate of growth of Y is :

$g_Y = g_A + g_L + \frac{f'(k^*)}{f(k^*)}\dot{k^*}$

with $k^*$ being the "steady state" of $k_t$ which comes by assuming that:

$\dot{k}_t = sA_tf(k_t) - (n+\delta)k_t = 0$

Then $g_Y$ is only known if $f$ is known.

Let's assume that:

$Y_t = A_t(aK_t^\rho + bL_t^\rho)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}$

then we can show that:

$Y_t = A_tf(k_t)$

with $k_t = \frac{K_t}{L_t}$ and:

$f(k_t) = (ak_t^\rho + b)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}$.

Can anyone help me with the expression for:

$\frac{f'(k^*)}{f(k^*)}\dot{k^*}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, as in most cases for the Solow model, **we don't know an explicit analytical solution of the differential equation for $k_t$,** the so-called *fundamental equation of growth*, and in general one must rely on a qualitative analysis, as exemplified by the usual graphs of the Solow model.

The fundamental equation of the Solow model with the *total factor productivity*  $A_t$ in general is:

$$\dot{k}_t = sA_tf(k_t) - (n+\delta)k_t \tag{1}.$$

Substitute into $(1)$ the expression of $f(k)$ for the $CES$ function, $f(k_t) = (ak_t^\rho + b)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}$,
to obtain:

$$\dot{k}_t = sA_t( (ak_t^\rho + b)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}) - (n+\delta)k_t \tag{2}.$$

**How to solve this differential equation in the unknown function $k_t$, in order to know explicitly $k_t$?**

Observe that:

1. Equation $(2)$ depends on the function $A_t$, which we don't know.
2. Even if we knew the function $A(t)$, it is highly probable that we are not able to solve analytically the differential equation $(2)$, because, unfortunately, in mathematics the class of differential equation we know how to solve is not very large, we don’t know how to solve very many differential equations.

As a consequence, we can’t know $k^*$.

As far as I know, the only case (of economic relevance) in which we know how to  solve explicitly, analytically, the Solow model is when  **the production function is a Cobb-Douglas.**

In this case, it can be shown that the fundamental equation reduces to a type of differential equation, the so-called *Bernoulli equation*, for which we have an explicit method of solution.

For an explanation, if you are interested,  you can  see my answer in this thread  about the Cobb-Douglas production function:
[Why is the Cobb-Douglas production function so popular?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18998/why-is-the-cobb-douglas-production-function-so-popular/55958#55958)

$$***$$

**[edit]**  It came to mind   that a discussion of the $CES$ production function case is in the classical paper by **Solow, [A contribution to the Theory of growth, 1956](http://piketty.pse.ens.fr/files/Solow1956.pdf),** pp. 77-78.

Solow examines the case $p={1\over {2}}$, so that the $CES$ production function becomes:

$$Y=(a\sqrt{K}+\sqrt {L})^2$$

And the fundamental equation becomes (he writes $r$ instead of $k$):

$$\dot r = s(a\sqrt r+1)^2-nr$$.

Then he points out that:

> The solution has to be given implicitly: $$\left(\frac{A\sqrt r+1}{
>  A\sqrt r_0+1}\right)^{1/A}\left(\frac{B\sqrt r+1}{ B\sqrt
>  r_0+1}\right)^{1/B}= e^{\sqrt {nst}}$$
>
> Once again it is easier to refer to a diagram.

Therefore, the problem is that we haven’t an explicit solution for $r$.

Moreover, here the total factor productivity $A_t$ is absent, and its eventual presence can evidently make things even more complicated.

Comment: I was afraid of that... thanks for your answer BakerStreet, I have been struggling with this for some weeks now...

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @Veronica I added a discussion of the CES case in the Solow's 1956 paper.